# Gluster 11, cannot make replicate volume

Tags: glusterfs, rocky-linux

I'm trying to single node volume, convert to replicate volume by adding one more brick to gluster volume. I'm using command:

gluster volume add-brick  replica 2

But every time I get Distributed-Replicate volume.

```
Type: Distributed-Replicate
Volume ID: 01fd7285-ce8c-4f52-8dd9-8b2f8c179074
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: s1:/storage/brick1/vol1
Brick2: s2:/storage/brick1/vol1
```

Please help!